# Dynamic Append input element as tree on click jquery

Tags: jquery, html

When I click 'Add' below I want the input element to appear for the parent. It works fine but all child elements execute instead of one. Also if I click any where in the body they execute, which I don't want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_field_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#maingroup_1").append('<div id="Subgroupmain">Add 1<input type="text"></div>');
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#Subgroupmain", function(e) {
    $("#Subgroupmain").append('<div id="SubSubgroupmain" style="margin: 0 0 0 23px;">Add 2<input type="text"></div>');
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", "#SubSubgroupmain", function(e) {
    $("#SubSubgroupmain").append('<div id="Sub3groupmain" style="margin: 0 0 0 53px;">Add 3<input type="text"></div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="maingroup">
    <div id="maingroup_1">
      <span class="add_field_button">Add </span>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: never duplicate ids.

Comment: I just want when I click "Add" a input element should appear as a child element . It is like three level unordered list.

Comment: @Kelvin B I understand your point but I was adding incremental number next to id's name. I remove code to keep as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here. Firstly you're repeating `id` attributes every time you append new content. Change those to classes instead. Then within the event handler use the `this` keyword to refer to the element which raised the event so that you only append to that single instance. Finally, add a call to `stopPropagation()` on the event to stop the event bubbling so that nested div elements don't raise multiple events which in turn append multiple divs. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_field_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#maingroup_1").append('<div class="Subgroupmain">Add 1<input type="text"></div>');
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".Subgroupmain", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).append('<div class="SubSubgroupmain" style="margin: 0 0 0 23px;">Add 2<input type="text"></div>');
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".SubSubgroupmain", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).append('<div class="Sub3groupmain" style="margin: 0 0 0 53px;">Add 3<input type="text"></div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="maingroup">
    <div id="maingroup_1">
      <span class="add_field_button">Add </span>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I place mouse to type in it generates new element automatically how could I prevent this , clicking on "add" a new input element should appear. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

You're using duplicate id's but the actual issue here is that you're appending to a general id rather than the click target.

Use this:

```
$(this).append();
```

Instead of:

```
$("#SubSubgroupmain").append();
```

Which should really be:

```
$(".SubSubgroupmain").append();
```

Comment: I understand your point but I was adding incremental number next to id's name. I remove code to keep as simple as possible.

Comment: This is the code $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
     e.preventDefault();
     if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<?php echo $warraper_invFields; ?>'); //add input box
     }
    });

Comment: You already accepted a different answer and there was no php in your question. I don't know where you're going with this.